# the 200 mile-journey or the 200-mile journey

Tags: punctuation

The original sentence:

> Because the Moon has only an eightieth of the Earth's mass, it
>   requires 97 per cent less energy to travel the quarter of a million
>   miles from the Moon to Earth-orbit than **the 200 mile-journey** from
>   Earth's surface into orbit!

Is the boldfaced part supposed to be **“the 200-mile journey”** in standard English?

Thanks for the help, as always.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The writer (or editor or typographer) put the hyphen in the wrong place. It happens a lot in publishing, usually as a result of carelessness but sometimes because the writer simply doesn't know how to use hyphens properly.

Comment: @SvenYargs I agree, I can only imagine a mile-journey being a journey of one mile. Not really applicable to space travel!

Comment: Lots of people would omit the hyphen entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

200-mile is correct. It is a compound adjective derived from an adjective+noun phrase as in: The journey was 200 (adjective) miles (noun). Note the noun is made singular in the conversion. It is common with numbers + noun, as in a three-metre rope, a 60-kilogram rock. Addition of a postpositive adjective to these can cause confusion. As in the pool was three metres deep = a three-metre-deep pool, NOT: a three-metre deep or three metre-deep or three metre deep pool.